# What is serial copy? And why it is implemented like this?

Tags: c++, memory-mapping

What is *serial* copy? Is it different from deep-copy and shallow-copy?

According to the wiki entry under [**Duff's device**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device), it is traditionally implemented as:

```
do {                //count > 0 assumed
    *to = *from++;  //Note that the 'to' pointer is NOT incremented
} while(--count > 0);
```

And then it makes a note, saying

> Note that `to` is not incremented because Duff was copying to a single memory-mapped output register.

I didn't really understand this note.

If `to` pointer is not incremented, then what is the point of the loop? Why then it is implemented as:

```
*to = from[count-1]; //does it not do the same thing?
```

I suspect that it has something to do with the definition of *serial* copy.

How can we allocate memory for `to` so that the loop would make some difference?

Comment: Maybe is a copy to a FIFO BUFFER. Eg. a hardware buffer for a device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point of such a copy is that it is not made to normal memory, but to a serial register.

So, each time a write is made to the address of the register (`to`), the hardware associated with the register will do something like send the bits over a serial link, or push them onto a queue for some other hardware to deal with.

Typically you cannot even read from register addresses like this, so they are very unlike normal `memory`, and best thought of as an interface to a particular piece of hardware that just happens to be located at a memory address.

Answer (score 4):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O#Example

Some platforms have special addresses that when you read from / write to it, the system will perform some I/O. For example, the `to` could be an address that controls the speaker when written. In that case, the loop would, e.g. be able to play a sound, while the `*to = from[count-1];` will not give any useful output.

Comment: I started to understand this. Could you please elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 2):

The `to` pointer here is "special". On certain hardware you can access IO ports by writing to special memory regions. If you wanted to send a bit pattern over an IO port, where the pattern was already in memory this is the sort of thing you'd do.

Every write to `to` causes the output from the IO port to be changed typically. This is for iterating over the pattern and writing it to the "special" memory.

How you get access to such "special" memory is very platform and implementation specific. Sometimes it's just a question of always writing to a fixed address - normally some platform header provides a `#define` or similar then to make that information available to you at compile time. Sometimes there's a system call you need to make that tells you the address a particular device you're interested in is mapped at.